# Two products over primes

Tags: products, prime-numbers

For $k \in \mathbb{N}$ define 
$$ f(k) = \prod_{\text{p prime}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^k(p^k+1)}\right)$$
$$ g(k) = \prod_{\text{p prime}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^k(p^k-1)}\right)$$

By the product for zeta $f(1)=\zeta(2)/\zeta(3)$.

With 100 digits of precision and Cohen's pari script $f(2)=21/(2\pi^2)$
,$g(1)=315/2\zeta(3)/\pi^4$.

Are the conjectured values correct?

Other closed forms?

Comment: Dear joro, The same argument that computes $f(1)$ shows that $f(k) = \zeta(2k)/\zeta(3k)$.  This explains the value of $f(2)$.  A similar argument shows that $g(k) = \zeta(2k)\zeta(3k)/\zeta(6k)$, which explains the value of $g(1)$.  Regards, 

Comment: http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/moree/Moree-txfm.en.shtml